# How do I set a custom value with animation on this React Circular Progress Bar?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking at [this repo](https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar/blob/HEAD/README.md#using-the-styles-prop) for a progress bar, and this code in particular is given as an example for a bar with animated bar and text transitions:

```
<Example label="Fully controlled text animation using react-move">
      <AnimatedProgressProvider
        valueStart={0}
        valueEnd={66}
        duration={1.4}
        easingFunction={easeQuadInOut}
        repeat
      >
        {value => {
          const roundedValue = Math.round(value);
          return (
            <CircularProgressbar
              value={value}
              text={`${roundedValue}%`}
              /* This is important to include, because if you're fully managing the
        animation yourself, you'll want to disable the CSS animation. */
              styles={buildStyles({ pathTransition: "none" })}
            />
          );
        }}
      </AnimatedProgressProvider>
    </Example>
```

With AnimatedProgressProvider.js being the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Animate } from "react-move";

class AnimatedProgressProvider extends React.Component {
  interval = undefined;

  state = {
    isAnimated: false
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    valueStart: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.repeat) {
      this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          isAnimated: !this.state.isAnimated
        });
      }, this.props.duration * 1000);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isAnimated: !this.state.isAnimated
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animate
        start={() => ({
          value: this.props.valueStart
        })}
        update={() => ({
          value: [
            this.state.isAnimated ? this.props.valueEnd : this.props.valueStart
          ],
          timing: {
            duration: this.props.duration * 1000,
            ease: this.props.easingFunction
          }
        })}
      >
        {({ value }) => this.props.children(value)}
      </Animate>
    );
  }
}

export default AnimatedProgressProvider;
```

This is obviously just an animated demo of the actual implementation with hard coded values. But I'm struggling to figure out how I would plug my own values into this and only have it animate and update when my value updates.

So lets say I have an API call for a value and when that value changes I want this to update. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer to this for anyone wondering. It's the value end variable that determines the "current" value and the "value start" is where the animation begins on page load